# Filters plugin in WP site

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I've added in function.php some code to create some filters in my WP site.
The script is the following:

```
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
    'field_1'   => 'forma', 
    'field_2'   => 'posa',
    'field_3'   => 'conduttore',
    'field_4'   => 'isolante',
    'field_5'   => 'raggio_minimo_di_curvatura',
    'field_6'   => 'guaina',
    'field_7'   => 'marchiatura',
    'field_8'   => 'tensione_di_esercizio',
    'field_9'   => 'temp_max_esercizio',
    'field_10'  => 'temp_min_di_inst',
    'field_11'  => 'temp_max_corto'
);


// action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }   

    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');


    // loop over filters
    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {

        // continue if not found in url
        if( empty($_GET[ $name ]) ) {

            continue;

        }


        // get the value for this filter
        // eg: http://www.website.com/events?city=melbourne,sydney
        $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);


        // append meta query
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );

    } 


    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

}
```

For the moment, this code only shows 10 empty rows but there are any checkbox or filter name.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: There is no need to check `if (empty($_GET['name']))` in the loop. You only need to check this once before you start looping. I'm not really sure what you mean with the following *For the moment, this code only shows 10 empty rows but there are any checkbox or filter name.*? Try to be more specific.

Comment: You maybe need to add a relation between your meta_query. meta_query expects nested arrays, even if you only have one query.